# gin how to check whether params was post or not

Tags: go, go-gin

```
type listParams struct {
    Status int `form:"status"`
    Keyword string `form:"keyword"`
    ShowType int `form:"show_type"`
}

func List(c *gin.Context) {
    var ReqData listParams
    _ = c.ShouldBind(&ReqData)
     
    // I fetch this by PostForm() to check it empy if it equal to empty string
    if stat := c.PostForm("status"); stat == "" {
        ReqData.Status = -99
    }

    // .......
}
```

In this code, How can I know that was front-end post the `status` or not?

Because of the default value of go, if I check the `reqData.Status == 0`, it will always return true if the front-end didn't post it, but In my case, `0` is a meaningful value, So I can't check it by equal to `0`.

So am I have the others way to check it?

PS: I tried and found out that `gorm` will not update the field in struct if I don't assign:

```
var d &User{} // User is a definition of user table
d.ID = 1
d.Name = "Joy"
// d.Status = 1 // It has this field, but I dont assign it
db.Model(&User{}).updates(&d)
```

Finally, `status` won't update to `0`(In my understanding, `d.Status` should be `0`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer type to circumvent the 0 default value:

```
type listParams struct {
    Status &int `form:"status"`
    Keyword string `form:"keyword"`
    ShowType int `form:"show_type"`
}
```

The check if `d.Status` is `nil`, otherwise get the associated value

Answer (score 0):

I think this constraint raises the need for having a sole public way to construct User.

```
type user struct { Status int Keyword string ShowTypeint}
func NewUser() (*user) { return &user{Status: -1} }
```

That way you ensure that user struct is only constructed through NewUser having Status default value Status always equal to -1.